# Every metric space can be embedded isometrically into the Banach space

Tags: functional-analysis, metric-spaces, banach-spaces

I've been trying to construct my own proof of this, but the only reference I've been able to find that I could (somewhat) understand was the following. In particular, I'm confused at the use of $f_{a}(a)$ and $f_{b}(a)$ in proving that $\|f_{a} - f_{b}\| = d(a, b)$. I realize there's an almost identical question, but it's ~4 years old and received one response which didn't help my understanding.

The proof goes as follows:

Let $X$ be a set and $B(X, \mathbb{R})$ the set of bounded functions $f: X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with norm $\|f\| = \sup_{x \in X}\{|f(x)|\}$. Then every metric space $(X, d)$ can be embedded isometrically into the Banach space $E = \text{Bou}(X, \mathbb{R})$.

Proof. One can assume $X \neq \emptyset$. Fix a point $a_{0} \in X$ and for every $a \in X$ define a function $f_{a}: X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ by
$$
f_{a}(x) = d(x, a) - d(x, a_{0}).
$$
Then $|f_{a}(x)| \leq d(a, a_{0})$ for every $x \in X$ so $f_{a}$ is bounded. Set $g: X \rightarrow E$, $g(a) = f_{a}$. Then we have the mapping $g: X \rightarrow E$, and it now remains to prove that $g$ is an isometry.

Let $a, b \in X$. As $x \in X$, it can be shown that
$$
|f_{a}(x) - f_{b}(x)| = |d(x, a) - d(x, b)| \leq d(a, b).
$$
Therefore $\|f_{a} - f_{b}\| \leq d(a, b)$. On the other hand
$$
|f_{a}(a) - f_{b}(a)| = |d(a, a) - d(a, a_{0}) - d(a, b) + d(a, a_{0})| = d(a, b).
$$
Therefore $\|g(a) - g(b)\| = \|f_{a} - f_{b}\| = d(a, b)$.

End Proof.

I can understand how the proof is able to show that $|f_{a}(x)|$ is bounded for every $x$. I also understand how they derived the inequality $|f_{a}(x) - f_{b}(x)| \leq d(a, b)$. Where I'm lost is how the use of $|f_{a}(a) - f_{b}(a)| = d(a, b)$, shows that the equality holds (required for an isometric embedding). I would assume the fact that just prior, we established that $|f_{a}(x) - f_{b}(x)| \leq d(a, b)$ challenges the idea that the equality case is meaningful.

Comment: What this proves is firstly that for all $a$, $b$ and all $x$, we have $|f_a(x) - f_b(x)| \le d(a, b)$. Taking the supremum over $x$ shows that $||f_a - f_b|| \le d(a, b)$. Now we want to show $||f_a - f_b|| \ge d(a, b)$. Remember that $||f_a - f_b||$ is defined by a supremum over $x$. So it suffices to exhibit one $x_0$ with $|f_a(x_0) - f_b(x_0)| \ge d(a, b)$. The proof shows that $x_0 = a$ does the job. Remember that the output of the function $g$ is a function, and we're trying to show something about the distance between these functions.

Comment: So if I understand your comment correctly, $|f_{a}(x) - f_{b}(x)| \leq d(a, b)$ establishes that there is no $x$ for which $\sup_{x \in X}\{|f_{a} - f_{b}|\}$ will surpass $d(a, b)$, then because we are looking at the supremum, we just need to show there is one $x_{0}$ that produces an equality (for any $a, b$), for which $x_{0} = a$ suffices?

Comment: I think that's right (although $\sup_{x \in X} \{|f_a - f_b|\}$ doesn't make sense - is that a typo?). Does that make sense to you? Are you happy with the following facts: **(1)** "if $h(y) \le k$ for all $y \in Y$, then $\sup_{y \in Y} h(y) \le k$", **(2)** "if $h(y_0) = K$ for some $y_0 \in Y$, then $\sup_{y \in Y} h(y) \ge K$" **(3)** "what we need to show to prove $g$ is an isometry is that for all $a, b$, we have $d(a, b) \le \sup_{x \in X} |f_a(x) - f_b(x)| \le d(a, b)$"? This proof just makes use of these three facts put together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To summarise the discussion in the comments, fix $a,b\in X$. By definition,

$$\|g(a) - g(b)\| = \sup_{x\in X}|[g(a) - g(b)](x)| = \sup_{x\in X}|(f_{a} - f_{b})(x)| = \sup_{x\in X}|f_{a}(x) - f_{b}(x)|.$$

So the result follows by showing that

$$\sup_{x\in X}|f_{a}(x) - f_{b}(x)| = d(a,b).$$

Showing that $|f_{a}(x) - f_{b}(x)| \leq d(a,b)$ for all $x\in X$ allows you to conclude that $d(a,b)$ is an upper bound for $\{|f_{a}(x) - f_{b}(x)| : x\in X \}$, from which it follows that

$$\sup_{x\in X}|f_{a}(x) - f_{b}(x)| \leq d(a,b).$$

On the other hand, showing that $|f_{a}(a) - f_{b}(a)| = d(a,b)$ allows you to conclude that

$$d(a,b) = |f_{a}(a) - f_{b}(a)| \leq \sup_{x\in X}|f_{a}(x) - f_{b}(x)|.$$

This obtains the desired equality.